# TimeSpan in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to get lambda function that will query for items which were submitted in the last minute. How to specify this?

```
var items= Items.Where(i=>DateTime.Now.Subtract(i.Date)...)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the items each have a Date property, you could do:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(0,1,0);
var items = Items.Where( i => i.Date >= startDate );
```

You could put the math into the Where statement directly, but it would get recomputed on each item, so I prefer to keep the starting time out of the statement.

Comment: I used this for reason described

Answer (score 9):

Take your pick

```
var items= Items.Where(i => DateTime.Now.Subtract(i.Date).TotalMinutes < 1)
```

or

```
var items= Items.Where(i => DateTime.Now.Subtract(i.Date).TotalSeconds <= 60)
```

Comment: I like the second one. It looks symmetrical with the => and <=.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
DateTime cutoffPoint = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);
var items = Items.Where(i => (i.Date >= cutoffPoint));
```

Comment: You probably meant `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1);` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = Items.Where(i => DateTime.Now.Subtract(i.Date).TotalSeconds <= 60);
```

Depending on how much items your list contains you might want to save DateTime.Now to a variable, so it's the same over all comparisons..

Comment: I think you mean `.TotalSeconds` and not `.Seconds` - that would always be < 60.